# When returning content from getInitialProps, is there a method to check for empty?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am quite new to React & NextJS, coming over from the PHP language. This is quite fun and exciting for me - but haven't been able to grasp this part yet.

Can you check for empty in the ***getInitialProps***? For instance, show an error message if the API is down or the API doesn't return any results?

Forgive me for posting my code, but here it is...

```
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import Layout from '../components/Layout'; 
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import 'isomorphic-fetch'; // Library for fetching data 
import Link from 'next/link';
import {Jumbotron, Button, Row} from 'reactstrap';

export default class Index extends React.Component {
  static async getInitialProps() {

        // Connect to the API
        const ApiResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/mods')

       // Store the data fetched from ApiResponse
       const ModsData = await ApiResponse.json()

        // return mods (first is table name in API, second is the ModsData variable above where we store the json data)
        return {
          mods: ModsData

        }


  }
  render() {
    return <Layout>



     <span style={{borderBottom: '1px solid #ccc', paddingBottom: '5pt', marginTop: '5pt'}}>

     <h4 style={{paddingTop: '10pt'}}>Showing all mods</h4>
     </span>

      <ul className="list-group" style={{paddingTop: '10pt'}}> 
        {this.props.mods.map(Mod => // Get our mods & loop over them
       <li className="list-group-item" key={Mod.id}>
        <Link as={`/mods/${Mod.id}`} prefetch href={`/mods/id=${Mod.id}`}><a>

        {Mod.name}</a></Link>
        {Mod.description}

        </li>

        )}
        </ul>
    </Layout>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another prop `noData`, and check if the `ModsData` is returning anything, if not that add `noData: true` else `noData: false`

```
    static async getInitialProps() {
        let noData = false
        // Connect to the API
        const ApiResponse = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/mods').then((value) => {
            if(!value) noData = true;
        }).catch(err => {
            noData = true;
        })

       // Store the data fetched from ApiResponse
       const ModsData = await ApiResponse.json()

        // return mods (first is table name in API, second is the ModsData variable above where we store the json data)
        return {
          mods: ModsData,
          noData
        }
  }

 render(){
      if(this.props.noData) return <h1>No Data</h1>

      //return other code
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Ertan, do you have an example of where & how I would define that?

Answer (score 1):

try and catch is perfect for this right? if error you can set `error` as part of your props